# Staying in the same Shell session with Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I am building a Python script that will automatically create and arrange my new Django projects.

What I'm doing is;

- create a virtualenv
- activate the virtualenv with `source my_app/bin/activate`
- pip install `toolname` (multiple times)
- django startproject
- django startapp (multiple times)
- mkdir `` `dirs `` (making template dirs, assets, etc.)
- open `./my_app/my_app/settings.py` and edit the inners (based on the script's input)
- open `./my_app/my_app/urls.py` and edit (unlock) the admin portion
- create the default `admin.py` and `urls.py` files for the apps
- auto-download the latest JavaScript libraries, images etc.

Now the issue is that I want Python's Shell (`os.system('source my_app/bin/activate')`) to keep it's session, so that I enter that Virtual Environment and then can `pip install` from the python script.

Now when I do;

```
os.system('virtualenv ' + virtualenv_name)
os.system('source ' + ve_path + 'bin/activate')
os.system('which python')
```

It still tells me it's in `/bin/python` but should be in `/path/to/my_app/bin/python`.

Does anyone know if there is a native way (so my teammates don't have to install more than `virtualenv` in the main environment) to keep a shell's session alive?

I was thinking of chaining multiple commands and concat them into one shell command, but that's kind of ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is when you source a bash file, it doesn't really launch a new shell, but rather executes in the current shell, which is how it can actually change environment variables there.  Your `os.system('source ' + ve_path + 'bin/activate')` indeed launches a new bash and the changed environment variables disappear when that shell terminates.

At least on my system virtualenv generates a `activate_this.py` file too. line two in that file explains how to use it. It's an python version of the activate bash code.

Try putting this in your code instead of the source line: (oh well, I called my environment "A", but I bet you got the idea now)

```
activate_this = 'A/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```